# How to see logs from two different devices with "building and debugging"

Tags: iphone, xcode

First time doing some 2 player blue tooth stuff, and having some issues. I would like to be able to see the logs of both my devices, rather than just one

is there a trick to building and running on two devices in xcode? I just can't see it anywhere.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked in Organizer? You can see device logs in there.

In Xcode -> Window -> Organizer. Then select a device and click the device log's tab. With my experience with multiplayer bluetooth I was using this for one device and using Xcode debugging another.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably build and run on one device, and look at the console output of the other in the Organizer. I don't have another device on hand to test this, but I'd bet you can.